# How do I execute an INSERT using SqlCommand?

Tags: asp.net, html, windows, database

I have another [class that creates the connection](http://forums.asp.net/t/1193643.aspx) (see refined class half way down page) and I believe it connects or at lest I do not hit any of the exceptions in run time.

I would now like to insert data into my database but nothing is updated.
I am trying to follow [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) example but it is for reading.

I did run "querystring" on the show SQL Pane and it does execute correctly. It inserts data properly as  a new row.

not sure what to do after my last line? Thanks.

```
string queryString =
"INSERT INTO UserData UserProfileID, ConfidenceLevel, LoveLevel, HappinessLevel) VALUES ('a051fc1b-4f51-485b-a07d-0f378528974e', 2, 2, 2);";

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection database = new MySqlConnection();
        database.CreateConn();

        Command = new SqlCommand(queryString, database.Connection);  //

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

By the way, you're missing a parenthesis in your SQL query string.

And of course, you'd use parameters in a real query (and you will not use string concatenation instead of passing parameters as it'll open doors for destructive SQL injection attacks).