# MS SQL apotrophe in prompt in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to deal with an apostrophe in a prompt field in my SQL statement.  Example below :

```
WHERE propertyfieldintable=@promptfromuser
```

The problem is that there are addresses with an ' eg. Wood's therefore the SQL works for all other addresses except those with an '.

I have tried to use `replace(@promptfromuser,"'","''")` but keep getting an error (missing right ').  The `propertyfieldintable` is a text field so am assuming it needs a text input from the prompt.

I would appreciate any straightforward suggestions as the query is not in the database itself but sits within a reporting tool so can't take functions.

Comment: Apostrophes are accepted in parameters without using REPLACE. What are your exact errormessage?

Comment: You really ought to be using paramaterised SQL ... have a read of this stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216233/what-is-passing-parameters-to-sql-and-why-do-i-need-it/3216331

Answer (score 2):

You need to use parameters.

Comment: Maybe explain why...OP obviously hasn't heard of SQL injection etc

Answer (score 0):

Try the following replace statement

```
replace (@promptfromuser,'''', '''''')
```

Forget using " in databasecontext for ever. Microsoft has [] syntax to denote identifiers containing special characters.