# Append values to a column value in database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I want to append a large string values with the existing values of a column value in DB. this column is set as `nvarchar(MAX)`. But when I am trying, only first few parts of new string is appending with old value. Others are not appending. Please suggest .

```
string initial_result ="xxxxxx";//reading values from db column and assigning to string
string final_result="yyyyyyyyyy";//lengthier one
SqlCommand cmd71 = new SqlCommand("update details set  result='" + initial_result + "'+'"+finalresult+"' where student_id ='11' ", con7);
cmd71.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: [Use Command Parameters.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216233/what-is-passing-parameters-to-sql-and-why-do-i-need-it) This will make the code better *and* "magically fix" the problem. Also, depending on the actual operation it may be possible to skip "reading" in `initial_result`. And, as always, strive for a normalized database..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using unnecessary single quotes when you concatenate `initial_result` and `finalresult` values.

```
result='" + initial_result + "'+'"+finalresult+"'
                                ^               ^
```

But more important, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your database connections and objects.

```
using (SqlConnection con7 = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
   using (SqlCommand cmd71 = con7.CreateCommand())
   {
       cmd71.CommandText = "update details set  result = @result where student_id ='11'";
       cmd71.Parameters.Add("@result", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = initial_result + finalresult;
       cmd71.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"update details set result=result+'" + finalresult +  "' where student_id ='11'"
```

this would append, and u'll no need to read to initial_result

Comment: I don't think this will generate same result. It generates same results only if `result` column has `initial_result` where `student_id ='11'`. Also using string concatenation is not a good approach. Parameterized queries always recomended.

Answer (score 0):

As "Soner Gönül" mentioned to avoid Sql Injection attack, Format your code like this :

```
//reading values from db column and assigning to string
string initial_result ="xxxxxx";
//lengthier one
string final_result="yyyyyyyyyy";
string connectionstring = "your connection string here";
string query = "update details set  result=@result where student_id = 11";
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
{
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
   con.Open();
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@result", initial_result + finalresult));
   int executeresult = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   if(executeresult > 0)
   {
      Response.Write("Update Success");
   }
   else
   {
      Response.Write("Unable to Update");
   }
   cmd.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use `ToString()` method for `initial_result` and `finalresult` since they are already strings.