# MS SQL DATEPART inside the String.Format

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have this MS SQL query inside the String.Format:

```
    string sqlCommandx = String.Format("SELECT CASE WHEN sum(d1) > 0 THEN sum(n1)/sum(d1) ELSE null END as metricScore1 FROM DataBridgeStage Where programID={0} and DATEPART(m,reportingDate) = {1} and DATEPART(yyyy,reportingDate) = {2}",
            ProgramID, month, year);
```

I'm getting an error that says:  SQL logic error or missing database\r\nno such column: m.  Is there a a problem with my syntax?

Comment: `DATEPART(m,reportingDate)` Do you have the `m` column in the table?

Comment: You have a comma `,` after `metricScore1` and immediately before the `from` which is a syntax error in SQL... but my guess is why you're getting the error you are is because you don't have the `+` at the end of the 2nd line of text.  You need to fix both

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216233/what-is-passing-parameters-to-sql-and-why-do-i-need-it

Comment: I don't have issues with the commas and pluses( +).  This one is working when I ran it in MS SQL :

 SELECT DATEPART(m,GETDATE()), DATEPART(yyyy,GETDATE())

Comment: Good luck @Bot - you've just lost my interest in your problem, as you appear to have thrown my suggestion away without realising what I'm telling you

Comment: I didn't mean that. I'm sorry @freefaller

Comment: Don't build SQL using string concatenation (either directly using `+` or using string.Format). Use *parameters*. It's what they're designed for, and  it's a safe approach which means you don't have to worry about SQL Injection.

Comment: What are the values of the ProgramID, month, year arguments?

Comment: ProgramID = 1, month = 1, year = 2016

Comment: have you tried replacing this part DatePart(m,reportingDate) with Datepart(month,reportingDate)?

Comment: Yes, here's the error:
"SQL logic error or missing database\r\nno such column: month"

Comment: Please tag what database system you're using. Most people seeing C# and just "sql" may assume SQL Server but "SQL logic error or missing database\r\nno such column: month" isn't a SQL Server error message and datetime functions vary between database systems.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Are you **sure**? Because when I google the phrase "SQL logic error or missing database", all of the hits I'm finding are for SQLite.

Comment: Yes my source data is from MS SQL and I have a service that migrate the data to SQL Lite.

Comment: Well, the database you're sending that query to is the SQLite one, not the SQL Server one, and *my* mention of SQLite was the first one that's turned up here.

Comment: Thanks. That would help @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106378/discussion-between-bot-sundi-and-damien-the-unbeliever).

Comment: How to get the month number of a date using SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the fixed.  But I would like to thank @Damien_The_Unbeliever.  I didn't think that it's a SQLite issue.  In this case, I used the SQLite syntax.  Here's the syntax:

```
string sqlCommandx = String.Format("SELECT CASE WHEN sum(d1) > 0 THEN sum(n1)/sum(d1) ELSE null END as metricScore1 FROM DataBridgeStage Where programID={0} and strftime('%m',reportingdate) = '{1}' and strftime('%Y',reportingdate)  = '{2}'",
        ProgramID, month, year);
```

Answer (score -2):

the correct form to use String.Format is:

```
String.Format("{0} {1}",one,two);
```

Comment: The correct form is not to use `string.Format()` for SQL.